# How to close app using exit and back button

Tags: android, activity-finish

In my app I have menu page that contains 4 buttons History, Types, Benefits and Exit. After Splash Screen menu page opens. If I start History, Type or Benefit activity. I am not finish menu activity because if I finish this then on press on navigating up icon in action bar app close. When I am in any of the 3 activities and press device back button then I came back to menu activity. And if then I press exit or back button from device. EndSplash starts and app finish thats I want. But after one second app restart. How to close app on exit and back button?

I also have navigating tabs below action bar. Minimum API level 8.

In menu activity-

```
exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EndSplash.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
@Override 
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EndSplash.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

And in History,Types and Benefits Activity-

```
public void onBackPressed()  
    {    
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));  
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to exit app. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon

Comment: As Raghunandan asked:) I'm curious as well as normally you would not "exit" the application as next time user needs to wait longer for application to open.

Comment: You have an EndSplashScreen, showing when the user leaves the app ? To me, that is terrible UX, completely out of touch with how Android usually works...

Comment: @2Dee I know but why the above code is not finishing all activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to Exit the application:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use a `BroadcastReceiver` on button press you should finish all the activities registered to it. you should register all the activities on its `oncreate()`. There are lot of implementations out there for broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

To finish all your activities you can make a Utils.java class and add this method on it:

```
public static List<Context> listContext = new ArrayList<Context>();

public static void finishActivities() 
{

    System.out.println("inside finishActivities:: ");

    for (Context context : Utils.listContext) {
        if(context!=null)
         ((Activity) context).finish();
    }
    Utils.listContext.clear();
}
```

and add your activity context to list like:

```
Utils.listContext.add(this);
```

and call this method from your onBackPressed() Activity like:

```
Utils.finishActivities();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
PackageManager pm1 = context.getPackageManager();
List<android.content.pm.ResolveInfo> activities = pm1.queryIntentActivities(homeIntent, 0);
String className = activities.get(0).activityInfo.taskAffinity;
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startMain.setPackage(className);
context.startActivity(startMain);
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Comment: Whenever I start my app for first time and press home button app has to resume and start from that point on next time. But its start from start. After that whenever I run my app and press home its resume from that point.